# USB audio input is only picking up left channel and treating it as stereo

Tags: windows, usb, audio, usb-audio

I have an old mixer/USB audio interface combo (specifically, a Behringer Xenyx QX1622USB) that I am trying to record with.

Flow:
`instrument -> mixer/audio interface -> laptop`

The mixer part of it has stereo output, and this should be also output over its USB link.
However, Windows (my Windows 11 laptop; also tested on my brother's Windows 10 laptop) is only receiving the left channel, and treating it as stereo.

Does anyone know why this is happening?
Is this a "common" issue, or is it something audio interface/driver specific?

Comment: You are not being clear. Are you using it to record something else's line out or so, or are you connecting its line out to something's line in?

Comment: I think I clarified it. Better now, @TomYan?

Comment: Are you sure the instrument is generating Stereo ? Is there some configuration on the MIXER ??

Comment: The mixer shows the volume of the left and right channels for the main mix. I can adjust the pan of inputs. Panning something all the way to the left makes it come through clearly, but nothing comes through when the input is panned all the way to the right.

Comment: I have the same problem with a Xenyx Q1202